# Etymology of 'but', from West Germanic to Old English

Tags: english, etymology, germanic-languages

> [but (adv., prep.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=but&searchmode=none) [<--]     Old English *butan, buton* "**unless**, except; `without`, `outside`,"
>   from West Germanic * *be-utan*, a compound of *** *be-* "by"** (see [by](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=by&allowed_in_frame=0))
>   + * *utana* "out, outside; from without,"  from ***ut* "out"** (see [out](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=out&allowed_in_frame=0) (adv.)).
>   Not used as a conjunction in Old English. As a noun from late 14c.

How did the two bolded West Germanic etymons (*** *be-***  + ***ut***), combine to mean **unless**?

My guess: If an object is **out by** you, then the object is `outside` (of) you. To wit, you are `without` the object.
But how does this evolve to mean **unless**?

Please expose, explain, and bridge all hidden, missing semantic drifts and links. What is a right way of interpreting the etymology, to understand how the semantic jumps abstracted and strayed from the original literal meaning?

I don't quote [OED](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/254428/50720), whose etymology stops at Old English and so doesn't retrograde enough.

Comment: The etymology which leads an OED entry may stop at the point where the word enters English or achives its  distinct phonological character; but the following entries and citations are also etymological, providing a history of the word's use.

Comment: It is archaic now, but _without_ used to be used as a conjunction synonymously with _unless_. For example _without he is forced_ in [The New Hoyle](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2BtZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%22without+he+is%22&source=bl&ots=ZnQr3XiYwQ&sig=p2xiLHA4TvzyCPe9qoA6JWwrK7o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kn6KVfLEBumw7Aamp7ngDg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22without%20he%20is%22&f=false)

Comment: Of course we must not forget the Yorkshire song 'On Ilkla meear baht at' ('on Ilkley Moor without a hat')

Comment: @ColinFine That change I also question; how did `without` evolve to mean `unless`?

Comment: OED gives the following: "10. a. Introducing a condition: If not, unless, except. arch. c888   Ælfred tr. Boethius De Consol. Philos. xli. §2   Ðu segst þæt Nan þing wyrþe, bute hit God wille." *and* "4. So after a negative, expressed or implied. (Here but regularly translates Latin nisi, and may be explained as ‘unless, if not’. **It has been treated as a conjunction from the earliest times**.)" [emphasis mine - Alex B.]

Comment: OE outside, without =>leaving out, barring, except => unless" (unless means except if)

Comment: It honours you if you think that everything in etymology and semantic change can be explained in all details and absolute certainty. Unfortunately  that is not so. And I think " but"  will remain a bit mysterious inspite of all explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know enough about West Germanic (or Dutch) to trace the etymology of composition of *be* ("by") and *ut/utan*.  However, here are a few observations on that topic.

1. In OE, you have both ***utan*** ("outside") and ***innan*** ("inside").  Often found side by side (just as we do today): "inside and outside" => *innan and utan* (e.g. Genesis 1320).<sup>1</sup>
2. Not only do you have ***butan*** as "outside => except/unless" but also ***binnan*** "within", formed on the same model (*be+innan*).
      So yes, the adjunction of *be* ("by", PDG *bei*) to indicate a positioning relative to self is confirmed.  PDG still has *innen* and *binnen*.  
   Dutch as well retains *binnen* and *buiten*.<sup>2</sup>
     
      If you think of it, it is also present in Present Day English: that's the *with-* in *within* and *without*.
   So far so good.
3. Now about the **semantic shift** from "**outside**" to "**unless**" which ultimately led to the displacement of *ac/ak* (the "but" as a conjunction in Old English).  
   Here are a few examples I picked from the corpus of Old English Poetry gradually evolving from from "outside" to "unless".  All 'translations' are mine and are deliberately literal in order to facilitate the word to word correspondence.

   1. Let's start with a real meaning of "outside".  This is from the Genesis (as you can recognise). v 1355.

      > Feowertig daga fæhe ic wille  
      > on weras stælan and mid wægþreate  
      > æhta and agend eall acwellan  
      > þa **beutan** beo earce bordum  
      > þonne sweart racu stigan onginne.

      > For forty days [my] vengence I will
      > on mankind set, and with a deluge 
      > all possessions and possessors destroy
      > that **outside** are [of the] Ark's boards
      >  
      > when the black storm begins

      In this excerpt, we even have a more archaic form *beutan*.  Clearly, the intended meaning here is "outside".
   2. Here is an example taken from The Meters of Boethius: (20).

      > Hwæt, þu, fæder engla, eall þing birest e[ð]elice **buton** geswince.

      > What, Thou, Father of Angels, all things bearest easily, never tired.

      Here we don't have "outside" but more like "immune to" => "except" (fatigue).
   3. Finally, here is a sample meaning of "except/unless". Pater Noster (ii)

      > Ac hwar cym heo nu, **buton** þu, engla god,

      > But where comes she [the soul] now, **except/unless** from Thee, God of Angels.

      As a bonus, we can see here in the same sentence, that "but" is 'ac'/'ak'.

---

1. As well as *ufan and utan* "above and outside" for the rhyme.
2. In Dutch, *innen* has survived as a verb: "to cash in"

Comment: In Dutch, *buiten* is an adjective and adverb meaning "outside" (literally). The adjective can also be used in the sense "aside of", "apart from", "except"; this is similar to how "but" / "but for" can be used as an adjective in English.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please explain the reasoning behind the semantic shift from "outside" to "unless"? I read your entire helpful answer, but I still can't bridge this semantic jump.

Comment: @LePressentiment. I think you can get a first idea from the 3rd example.  Try once with "outside" and once with "except" and then with "unless". "But where comes [the soul] now, **outside** from Thee, God of Angels" (meaning the soul can only come from **within** God). And then "But where comes [the soul] now, **except** from Thee, God of Angels" (same but not in spatial referential). And eventually "But where comes [the soul] now, **unless** from Thee, God of Angels".  Of course it helps that the question is a "where from?".  But that's precisely where I think the analogy originated....

Comment: @LePressentiment... In my view the analogy is shifting from a spatial referential (in which outside has the information) to a probabilistic referential (more adapted to immaterial things which don't have a physical location) in which except or unless is the equivalent information.  In my example, the soul is in both world: it seems to be located somewhere but actually it's immaterial. So both meanings are valid. hence the shift.  A classical synaesthesia example: from concrete/visible to abstract/imaginary.